# Accessing git commit history, tags, etc from php

Tags: php, git, codeigniter

I'd like to be able to output my commit history essentially as a change log directly on a production site. Right now I'm thinking the best way to do this is to run whatever commands give me what I want via `exec()` but I don't see much out there around this sort of thing.

1. Is `exec()` an appropriate way to pull this into an app?
2. Are there security concerns I'm overlooking (since I don't see much about it)?

Comment: Instead of executing that command everytime you load the side, couldn't you just store the output once, and read that from your site?

Comment: Yes, I would cache it server side.

Comment: It is even something that can be done in some sort of build / deploy step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php

It's a nice PHP client for running Git commands, should be a lot easier that doing `exec()` manually.